# Soap UI War Websphere liberty profile deploy Issue

Tags: soapui, websphere-liberty

I am trying to deploy a war file which is generated using soap ui software(open soapUI-->right click on project-->Deploy as WAR) in websphere application server liberty profile but i am not able to deploy and hit the endpoint of the wsdl file

Note : i can deploy that war file in tomcat server and i can hit wsdl endpoint from soapui

soup UI software version : 4.5.1
websphere application server V8.5

could you please provide steps to deploy a war file in websphere liberty profile

```
2016-04-05 15:01:14,664 ERROR [errorlog] com.eviware.soapui.support.SoapUIException: Failed to load project from file     [wsjar:file:/D:/Liberty-WS/usr/servers/mockWSServer/dropins/mockDefaultBinding_ICalculator.war!/WEB-INF/soapui/Calc-soapui-project-soapui-project.xml]
com.eviware.soapui.support.SoapUIException: Failed to load project from file [wsjar:file:/D:/Liberty-WS/usr/servers/mockWSServer/dropins/mockDefaultBinding_ICalculator.war!/WEB-INF/soapui/Calc-soapui-project-soapui-project.xml]
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject.loadProject(WsdlProject.java:426)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject.<init>(WsdlProject.java:261)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject.<init>(WsdlProject.java:212)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject.<init>(WsdlProject.java:207)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject.<init>(WsdlProject.java:192)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProjectFactory.createNew(WsdlProjectFactory.java:36)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProjectFactory.createNew(WsdlProjectFactory.java:24)
at com.eviware.soapui.mockaswar.MockAsWarServlet.initProject(MockAsWarServlet.java:103)
at com.eviware.soapui.mockaswar.MockAsWarServlet.init(MockAsWarServlet.java:79)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:325)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:622)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:469)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1060)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4553)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:301)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:954)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:266)
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:776)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Failed to load url; wsjar:file:/D:/Liberty-WS/usr/servers/mockWSServer/dropins/mockDefaultBinding_ICalculator.war!/WEB-INF/soapui/Calc-soapui-project-soapui-project.xml, 0 -
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.UrlWsdlLoader.load(UrlWsdlLoader.java:184)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.UrlWsdlLoader.load(UrlWsdlLoader.java:98)
at com.eviware.soapui.im.pl.wsdl.WsdlProject.loadProject(WsdlProject.java:333)
... 21 more
```

Comment: Try adding this to server.xml <classloading useJarUrls="true" /> I don't know if it'll work, but if the UrlWsdlLoader requires a jar or file url  it will fix it.

Comment: SoapUI [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/soap-mocking/deploying-mock-services-as-war-files.html) talks about tomcat. Also check if this [link](http://clmpractice.org/2015/01/07/how-to-enable-cors-with-rational-team-concert-ccm-running-on-a-websphere-application-server-was-8-5/) helps.